# Can we 'count' uncountable nouns using 'those'?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, demonstrative-pronouns

Is this example sentence grammatically correct?

> I like music that emanates life, such as those composed by Beethoven.

Music is an uncountable noun, but isn't "those" the plural of "that"? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not correct. Beethoven composed *music*, not ∗*musics*, so the demonstrative should take the singular form:

> I like music that emanates life, such as ***that*** composed by Beethoven.

Comment: So are all these sentences: [love behind those music](http://www.wattpad.com/story/16772837-love-behind-those-music-short-story-the-violinist), [Attend and enjoy those music](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g190356-d582489-r142094953-Philharmonie_Luxembourg-Luxembourg_City.html) and [when all those Music started making sense to me](https://www.facebook.com/fantasticguyz?_fb_noscript=1) all wrong and can be corrected by replacing "those" with "that"?

Comment: @GaoWeiwei Indeed. I note that all of those are posted by non-native speakers.

Comment: @StoneyB Is the noun 'music' still considered a non-count noun here even though it has been referenced by *that*? Or is 'music' as a separate, countable noun considered to be left out of *that music*?

Comment: @CarSmack Non-count nouns can take demonstratives and other determinatives: "I like this music, but not that." The music is divided into categories, and it is the body of music within each category, otherwise undifferentiated, which is pointed to, not individual "musics". Occasionally we do find it semantically necessary to pluralize ordinarily non-count nouns--"Ben & Jerry's markets 91 different ice creams"--but even here we prefer to avoid this by substituting a countable category--"Ben & Jerry's markets 91 **flavors** of ice cream".

Comment: Does the word 'music' in the first phrase remain a non-count noun in this sentence even though later in the sentence 'music' has been "divided into categories"?

Comment: @CarSmack Music is music, one and indivisible, even when it is categorized. It is not 'counted' grammatically, even when an idiom seems to call for it: "a music to be enjoyed, not analyzed".

Comment: If you wanted to refer to the plurality of the music Beethoven wrote, you could use "works", "pieces" or "compositions". These are countable nouns, and can take "those" as pronoun.